# Jest No Tests found

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

running docker mhart/alpine-node:8 on macOS with

> nodejs (6.10.3-r0) (18/18) 
>   yarn 0.24.6
>   jest 20.0.4

I have a __tests__/index.test.js file however, when running the code

`node_modules/.bin/jest --watchAll` I get the below output

> No tests found
>   In /usr/src/app
>   5 files checked.
>   testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.js?(x),**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x) - 1 match
>   testPathIgnorePatterns: /node_modules/,/src,**src** - 0 matches
>   Pattern: "" - 0 matches

I've re-installed the package numbers times but to no avail.

Comment: The way I fixed this was by changing my docker-compose command slightly. I changed `command: npm run cover && bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)` to `command: bash -c 'npm run cover && bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)'`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your output says that `testMatch` had `1 match`, which may be your `__tests__/index.test.js` file. It seems that your `testPathIgnorePatterns` is causing that test suite to be ignored.  `No tests found In /usr/src/app` says that Jest is looking for tests in `/usr/src/app`, and `testPathIgnorePatterns: /node_modules/,/src,src` says that Jest is ignoring files in `/src` directories.

Either point Jest to look at the location of your `__tests__/index.test.js` file if it is outside the /src directory, or stop `testPathIgnorePatterns` from ignoring the /src directory.

Answer (score 23):

If you have file structure such as the following

```
myFolder
│   myFile1.js
│   myFile2.js
│   ...
│   
└───__tests__
        myFile1.spec.js
        myFile2.spec.js
        ...
```

then you need to have in `jest.config.js` the following pattern for `testMatch` property:

```
testMatch: ['**/__tests__/*.js?(x)'],
```

A simple example of `jest.config.js`:

```
const jestConfig = {
  verbose: true,
  testURL: "http://localhost/",
  'transform': {
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  testMatch: ['**/__tests__/*.js?(x)'],
}

module.exports = jestConfig
```

Answer (score 16):

In package.json there is a pattern that is used to find test file. In this pattern, you can change it according to your file location or make it the global pattern.

I wrote a test, not in the specific folder and follow a naming convention `*.test.js` and change `testMatch`

```
"testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.(test).{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try running `jest` without any parameters. A key thing to note is the test file names have to follow the convention `*.test.js` or `*.spec.js`.

Comment: Is there a way to just use the `.js` extension instead of `test.js` or `spec.js`?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to run all the tests inside the **tests** folder you can simply do the following 
`jest __tests__ --watch`

Answer (score 4):

Moving the `__tests__` filter into `src` fixed the issue for me. Now its able to run the tests.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error while attempting to run tests in a submodule of a project.  Fixed the issue by testing the submodule in isolation, in a separate folder tree from the main project.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what this meant in practice?

Comment: Shoot I don't remember now.  Sounds like I either moved/copied the submodule folder out of the main project folder, or cloned it separately (if that's possible)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Typescript, I started getting the same `No tests found` error after I updated Typescript to 3.8.3 from 3.3. Updating jest and ts-jest from version 23.* to 25.* fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me i'm using the vscode plugin and the fix for me was in .vscode/settings.json add this setting right here

```
"jest.jestCommandLine": "node_modules\\.bin\\jest"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been wrestling with this annoying anonymous issue, but I find the tedious solution for it.
if you type the test command like this `npm test .\repeatString.spec.js` or `npm run test .\repeatString.spec.js` you've done it right but it won't work.

I just removed `.\` from the command and it worked perfectly **try it without `.\` before the file path**