# Jest unit Testing - No tests found

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am starting out with Jest unit testing.
I keep getting "No tests found" while running a jest unit test.

**Error description**

```
yarn test
    yarn run v1.3.2
    $ jest
    No tests found
    In E:\Course\Testing JavaScript\Jest Demo
      4 files checked.
      testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.js?(x),**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x) - 3 matches
      testPathIgnorePatterns: \\node_modules\\ - 4 matches
    Pattern:  - 0 matches
    error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

os : window 7 ,
node v : 8.6,
npm v : 5.4.2

```
folder structure :
Demo 
    package.json
    __tests__
           sum.js
           sum.test.js
```

**sum.js file:**

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
module.exports = sum;
```

**sum.test.js**

```
const sum = require("./sum");

test("adds 1 + 2 to equal 3", () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "JestDemo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "jest": "^22.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  }
}
```

So far, i have referred these articles 
[Stackoverflow-Jest No Tests found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741766/jest-no-tests-found)

A few more post on github too regarding the same issue but nothing helped.

**What i did so far :**

1) changed the script to point to folder containing test files:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest __test__"  // 
     from "test": "jest"
  }
```

2) tried changing folder structure.

Could someone help me figure out the problem ?

Comment: Move all tests in `/tests` folder

Comment: @sensorario - this works.In all formal docs, __tests__ is mentioned as the default folder but it didn't work for me.You should post this as an answer instead of comment.I will accept this as an answer

Comment: I've updated my answer with a piece of my configuration. Hope this can help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You appear to have placed both your code and test files in the same directory (`__tests__/sum.js` and `__tests__/sum.test.js`).  I don't think that's a specific reason for the failure you are seeing but its not the convention.

It should not be necessary to specify a folder to search unless your project is complete.  Run `jest` without any arguments, other than necessary options, and it will search the current directory an below.

The convention is either:

```
/root
  /src
    sum.js
    /__tests__
      sum.js
```

or:

```
/root
  /src
    sum.js
    sum.test.js
```

You can use `test` or `spec` in the latter example. `root` and `src` are up to you, `root` is normally the location of `package.json` and is where you invoke jest from (e.g. `myApp`).  `src` help differentiate from other app components like build and assets.

Comment: Perfect, in my case was the --watch flag. Thanks!

Comment: Oh my god, thanks Dave. I spent hours searching, and your comment was the only thing I found that said "if the files are in \_\_tests\_\_, remove the *.test.js

Thank you!