# Can I use WORKDIR in my Dockerfile with Github Actions? (Also, resolving Jest "No tests found")

Tags: docker, github, jestjs, dockerfile, github-actions

Can I use WORKDIR in my Dockerfile with Github Actions?

I am switching from one CI provider to Github Actions and found that I had a step that runs `docker run <temp_image> npm test -- --coverage` and something seemed to be altering the way my Jest test were run, compared to my previous CI, and I would receive the error:

```
No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
In /app
  18 files checked.
  testMatch: /**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x) - 1 match
  testPathIgnorePatterns: /.next/, /node_modules/, /testconfig/ - 16 matches
  testRegex:  - 0 matches
Pattern:  - 0 matches
```

That one testMatch would run correctly in my previous CI solution, using the same command.

Some with this error were accidentally ignoring their test path : [Jest No Tests found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741766/jest-no-tests-found)

I tried a bunch of different approaches -- the main hunch being that my tests were being run in the incorrect directory. Using my shotgun approach I tried:

- Specifying <rootdir> for testMatch and testPathIgnorePatterns
- Removing testPathIgnorePatterns altogether
- Specifying the --config path, also --no-cache, options for Jest
- Specifying the -w working directory on docker run options
- And a multi-command approach for docker run `/bin/sh/ (cd /app && npm test)`

Ultimately, I found this line in [Github Actions Docs: Dockerfile Instructions And Overrides](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/dockerfile-support-for-github-actions#dockerfile-instructions-and-overrides)

> GitHub sets the working directory path in the GITHUB_WORKSPACE environment variable. It's recommended to not use the WORKDIR instruction in your Dockerfile.

**Removing the WORKDIR instruction in my Dockerfile fixes my error**

**BUT,** Is there a way around having to remove WORKDIR from my Dockerfile? It seems to maybe be a [Docker best practice to use WORKDIR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51066379/8616544) and I would prefer to follow Docker guidelines than Github Actions.

Thank you for your time!